# Why does pthread_cond_signal sometimes not work?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, signals

My program performs "thread synchronization" using `pthread_cond_wait` and `pthread_cond_signal`.  It seems to fail about one in 20 times.

I have a shared variable `count` which is initialized to 0.
One thread increments `count` until `count` is 20 , then signals a condition variable.

The code is below.

```
void* inc_count(void *parm)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0 ; i <25; i ++)// adds count to 25
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);
        count ++;
        printf("Thread %lld , count = %d\n",(long long int)pthread_self(),count);
        if(count == 20)
        {
            pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
            printf("Thread %lld sends a signal!\n",(long long int)pthread_self());
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void* watch_count(void *parm)
{

    while(count < 20)
    {   
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);    
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond,&mutex1);
        printf("Thread %lld receives the signal!\n",(long long int)pthread_self());
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
int main()
{
    pthread_t pt1,pt2,pt3,pt4;
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex1,NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex2,NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&cond,NULL);
    pthread_create(&pt1,NULL,inc_count,NULL);
    pthread_create(&pt2,NULL,watch_count,NULL);
    pthread_join(pt1,NULL);
    pthread_join(pt2,NULL);

}
```

[image]

From the picture, you can see that thread pt2 didn't receive the signal, why?

Answer (score 3):

Your `watch_count()` function has problems:

- You're locking the mutex inside a `while` loop and only unlocking outside it (could try to lock more than once without unlocking)
- You don't hold the mutex when checking `count < 20`

To fix it, you need lock the mutex before the loop instead of inside it:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);    
while(count < 20)
{   
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond,&mutex1);
    printf("Thread %lld receives the signal!\n",(long long int)pthread_self());
}
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);
```

That will keep you from locking the mutex more than once before unlocking, and ensure that `count` can't be modified and the signal can't be sent between the test in the `while` condition and the `pthread_cond_wait` (`inc_count()`'s change to `count` and sending the signal would have to occur either before the while loop, or during the `pthread_cond_wait()`).

Even with those changes, there's still the possibility that the wait won't happen at all if `count` is already 20 by the time `watch_count()` checks it, though.

Comment: I don't see how it's possible for the mutex to be locked more than once since the condition variable is only signaled when the loop condition is false.  Likely your last sentence: i.e. that `watch_count` may not check `count` until it's already over 20 might cause the problem.

Comment: @SamSanjabi Even if it's unlikely to happen in this case, `pthread_cond_wait()` can be interrupted without the condition being signalled (a big part of why a `while` loop is used in the first place).  If it were, you'd get another loop iteration and an extra lock... which could deadlock, error out, or prevent the lock from releasing (depending on the details of the mutex).

Comment: @SamSanjabi Also, locking the mutex inside the loop body means the condition could be signalled after the `while` condition is tested but before the wait starts, resulting in a wait for a signal that never comes.

Comment: Thanks, I understand your second point -- but could you explain how `pthread_cond_wait()` could be interrupted without signalling the variable?  Are we talking about the process entering a signal handler?

Comment: @SamSanjabi If/how spurious wakeups might happen will depend on the implementation, but they're allowed and do happen sometimes.  This post on programmers.se talks a bit more about it: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/187089/36921

Answer (score 1):

@Dmitri's diagnosis at the end of his comment is the likely cultprit IMO: it's possible that your `inc_count` thread gets past 20 before the `watch_count` thread first checks the `while` condition.

Why use the while loop at all?  When `inc_count` sends the signal, you already know that the count is over 20, so why check for it?

My solution is to do some handshaking and make sure that `watch_count` enters its wait condition *before* `inc_count` starts counting.  To achieve this, you need to make sure that the following things happen in order:

1. `inc_count` enters its code first and then waits for `watch_count` to initialize
2. `watch_count` enters its code and signals `inc_count` that it's ready to go
3. `watch_count` waits for `inc_count` to signal it
4. `inc_count` starts counting and signals `watch_count` when it gets to 20

I achieved this by grabbing a mutex before starting either thread, then counting on the first thread to enter its "ready and waiting" condition before starting the second thread.  When the second thread is ready it signals the first thread to go ahead and start counting, here's my code:

```
void* inc_count(void *parm)
{
    // holding this mutex on entry;
    pthread_mutex_t* m = parm;
    int i;

    // wait for the watch_count thread to be ready
    pthread_cond_wait(&init_cond, m);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(m);

    // start counting
    for(i = 0 ; i < 10000; i ++)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&count_mutex);
        count++;
        printf("Thread %lld , count = %d\n", 
                       (long long int) pthread_self(),
                       count);

        if(count == 20)
        {
            pthread_cond_signal(&count_cond);
            printf("Thread %lld sends a signal!\n",
                           (long long int)pthread_self());
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&count_mutex);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void* watch_count(void *parm)
{
    // holding this mutex on entry
    pthread_mutex_t* m = parm;

    pthread_cond_signal(&init_cond);   // tell inc_count that you're ready
    pthread_cond_wait(&count_cond,m);  // wait for him to get to 20
    pthread_mutex_unlock(m);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&count_mutex);
    printf("Thread %lld receives the signal! count == %d\n",
                   (long long int)pthread_self(), 
                   count);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&count_mutex);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t pt1,pt2;
    pthread_mutex_t init_mutex, count_mutex;

    pthread_mutex_init(&init_mutex,NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&count_mutex,NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&init_cond,NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&count_cond,NULL);

    // this mutex is released when inc_count has initialized
    pthread_mutex_lock(&init_mutex);
    pthread_create(&pt1,NULL,inc_count,(void *) &init_mutex);

    // this mutex is released when watch-count has initialized
    pthread_mutex_lock(&init_mutex);
    pthread_create(&pt2,NULL,watch_count,(void *) &init_mutex);

    pthread_join(pt1,NULL);
    pthread_join(pt2,NULL);
}
```